# Javascript Function that shows and hides Div based on Checkboxes Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, display

So I'm building a form in HTML that makes use of a lot of checkboxes and hidden Divs. Right now I'm using

```js
function HideDiv1() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("Check1");
  var div = document.getElementById("Div1");
  
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    div.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Check1">CheckBox to show Div1
<div id="Div1" style="display: none;">I should be hidden, assuming the author didn't mess up!</div>
```

To hide each div based on the appropriate checkbox. But this means that I am copying and rewriting this function every time and the section where I like to keep my functions is getting quite large. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this such that I would only need one function and I could dynamically show and hide Divs without needing to copy and rewrite this function every time.

(If there is some easy JQuery solution to this: please keep in mind that I have no clue how to use JQuery)

This may be a duplicate, I saw the answer once before in the past but I have no idea how to find it again :(

Comment: You should avoid to use `.style` function in JS in 2021. The modern approach is to use `.classList` +
 `.add('class-name')` , `.remove('class-name')` or `.toggle('class-name')` to apply changes through CSS.
 This causes far less issues incl. possible specificity weight issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) to identify which `div` to show when the checkbox is changed.

You can do this by listening for the `change` event on each checkbox and toggling the corresponding `div` with [`jQuery.toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
  $('div[data-id='+$(this).data('target')+']').toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-target="1">CheckBox to show Div1
<div style="display: none;" data-id="1">Div1</div>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-target="2">CheckBox to show Div2
<div style="display: none;" data-id="2">Div2</div>
```

Vanilla JS implementation:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.matches('input[type=checkbox]')){
    let target = document.querySelector('div[data-id="'+e.target.dataset.target+'"]');
    target.style.display = target.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-target="1">CheckBox to show Div1
<div style="display: none;" data-id="1">Div1</div>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-target="2">CheckBox to show Div2
<div style="display: none;" data-id="2">Div2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would add an onchange attribute to the checkbox to call a single function called hideDiv and pass it two arguments that are the ids of the checkbox and the div that you are hiding with that checkbox:

```
onchange="hideDiv("check1","div1")"
```

...then hideDiv uses the arguments passed to it to toggle the correct div:

```
function hideDiv(checkId, divId) {
      const checkbox = document.getElementById(checkId)
      const div = document.getElementById(divId);

      if (checkBox.checked == true) {
          div.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          div.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Get in the habit of using **let** for variables that you need to change and **const** for variables that will not change value instead of **var**.